# Repeated data in vue

Tags: vue.js

i`m having a problem with my vue, the problem is im trying to print 2 words, that is 'A.2' and 'B.3', but when im printing it, it just show 'B.3' and 'B.3'. here is my code

this is a simple quiz project, so everytime a user choose option a with `true` status it should be adding 1 point to the score, i haven`t made that yet.

```
  <template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1 v-if="show">hai</h1>
    <h1 v-else>hehe</h1>
    <p>{{ nama}}</p>
    <input type="text" v-model="nama">
    <button type="button" v-on:click="hideTitle">Click Me</button>
    <h3> 1.Yang Dipakai Di sepatu adalah </h3>
    <p>{{ nama}}</p>
    <h3 v-for="j in jawaban">
    <input type="radio">
    {{j}}
    </h3>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data : function() {
  return{
    nama: 'Luthfi',
    show: true
    },
    {
    jawaban: 'A.2',
    correct: true
    },
    {
    jawaban: 'B.3',
    correct: false
    },
    {
    jawaban: 'C.4',
    correct: false
    }
    },
  methods: {
    hideTitle() {
      this.show = !this.show
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.nama = 'Fitra'
  }
  }
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

i expect there is 4 output from option A to D, but it kept showing me same option

Comment: Add the html part too !

Comment: i did, on the top

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `data()` returns only one object that contains

```
{
   nama: 'Luthfi',
   show: true
}
```

You must change this like:

```
data : function() {
    return{
        nama: 'Luthfi',
        show: true,
        jawaban: 'A.22',
        correct: true,
        jawabann: 'B.3'
    }
}
```

Comment: i`m sorry, but i edited my code a while ago, here is my code

Comment: i think i can't put different variable name for the true false statement, because i'm planning to make a method where i can add 1 point to the score based on the true false statement

Comment: it should be like this if (jawaban == true){skor += 1}